How to Submit a form without reloading page
How can i submit a form automatically when the page loads at once.
my code below. just reloads the page
<form method="POST" id="formID">
  <input type="text" name="item" value="food" />
</form>             
<script> 
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    document.getElementById('formID').submit();
  });
</script>


Submitting a form loads a page, by design.  Are you perhaps looking to use "AJAX" instead, with which you can write JavaScript code to send HTTP requests and read responses without loading a page?

https://yari-demos.prod.mdn.mozit.cloud/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX?retiredLocale=de

Here is a way submitting your form without reloading the whole page. Using Asynchronous AJAX.
To automatically submit a form on page load without reloading the page, you need to submit the form asynchronously using JavaScript.
Here is how you can do it:
<form id="myForm" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="item" value="food">
</form>

<script>
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const form = document.getElementById('myForm');

  // Submit form asynchronously via AJAX
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('POST', '/submit-url'); 
  request.send(new FormData(form));
});
</script>

The key points:

Use addEventListener('load') to wait for the full page to load
Create an XMLHttpRequest object to submit the form data asynchronously via AJAX
Open a POST request to the submit URL
Send the form data instance created from the form element

This allows submitting the form without reloading the page. The submit action is handled asynchronously in the background.
So in summary:

Get form element
Create XMLHttpRequest object
Open POST request
Send form data asynchronously

This is the JavaScript way to automatically submit a form on page load without reloading. Try out. I hope it might work on your purpose.

thanks @Md Shoriful Islam

welcome @201401 boss
